# How open, write and save opened txt file only via powershell?

Tags: powershell, text-files

I need open link to notepad.exe, write there some text and save this text in new file. After that I must close this file/

```
&("D:\4_курс\4_курс_1_семестр\Адміністрування_операційних_систем\Laba_2\FIO2\notepad.lnk")

New-Item D:\4_курс\4_курс_1_семестр\Адміністрування_операційних_систем\Laba_2\FIO2\notepad.txt

Set-Content D:\4_курс\4_курс_1_семестр\Адміністрування_операційних_систем\Laba_2\FIO2\notepad.txt 'Welcome to PowerShell'
```

I known how open link and how write to created file, but I don`t known save unsaved file, which is opened in powershell

Comment: Notepad.exe doesn't need to be involved; your `Set-Content` will write the data to the file. The file isn't "unsaved"; `Set-Content` opens the file, writes to it, and closes the file (saving the data written). Note that if you don't use the `-Append` switch, you will lose the old contents of the file (unless you have read them into a variable, updated the variable to include both the old and new text, and then written from the modified variable).

Comment: It appears that your native language may not be English; judging from your user name, I would guess that it's Russian. You may want to post this question to [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), where you may be more comfortable.  Похоже, что ваш родной язык не может быть английским; судя по твоему имени пользователя, я бы догадался, что это русский язык. Вы можете отправить этот вопрос в [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) языке, где вам будет удобнее.